# How do I get VS2008 to paste code without reformatting it (changing whitespace)?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, copy-paste

I did some code alignment in the way I preferred, using vim--then tried to paste it into VS2008.  Voila, 2008 decides to reformat it, removing all the whitespace I added to make some declarations beautifully aligned.

Is there a way to have VS2008 either (A) paste without changing whitespace or (B) align the code as shown below?

```
public int              SomePropertyName   { get; set; }
public Nullable<string> SomeOtherProperty  { get; set; }
public Nullable<int>    YetAnotherProperty { get; set; }
```

which ends up like this when I paste it into VS2008:

```
public int SomePropertyName { get; set; }
public Nullable<string> SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> YetAnotherProperty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Also, if you *like* the reformat most of the time, you can keep the option that Hans pointed out checked, and simply do a **ctrl + z** after you paste.  It won't undo the paste, but it will undo the reformatting of your code.  I prefer this method, since most of the time the reformat is a good thing.  But, when I don't like the results, **ctrl + z** and it's all better.

Comment: +1, that's the better solution.  I'll leave my answer for, ahem, reference.

Answer (score 5):

It is an option.  Tools + Options, Text Editor, C#, Formatting, "Automatically format on paste" check box.

Comment: VS2017 - Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting