# How do I stop VS2010 / ReSharper reformatting HTML on paste?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, copy-paste

I'm running ReSharper 6.1 in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 8. When I paste HTML into an HTML page it is auto-formatted. I'd rather it wasn't. There's [a neat solution proposed by Samuel Meacham](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3292853/575530) of using **ctrl + z** after the paste which undoes the formatting. But how do I turn it off entirely? I have Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Miscellaneous -> 'Format HTML on paste' unchecked and the ReSharper options do not mention pasting (at least as far as I can find) and just talk of reformat on enter or on closing tag. Is there a way to turn the ReSharper auto-formatting off for just pasting?

---------- edit ----------

Note that if I uncheck the ReSharper option 'Auto-format on enter' the auto-formatting on paste stops. Perhaps ReSharper does not let me differentiate 'paste' from 'enter'?

Comment: Are you sure you have the equivalent native VS option turned off? Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Misc > Format HTML on paste

Comment: Yes - that option is unchecked. I'll clarify the question a bit.